# Cocoa - how do programmatically decide the first window to show?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

Just new to the Cocoa Framework - I understand from  [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237833/how-does-xcode-decide-which-xib-to-show-first) that the first window is decided by a setting in the info.plist file.

For my application, the window to show is decided by some external settings. How do I set which is the first window to show during runtime?

Comment: Why do you understand from that question that the first window is decided by a preference setting? It says no such thing.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say by a setting within info.plist. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AppDelegate class, you will find a method called - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{} you have to create an instance of your window controller class of which you want to load and load the window.

Comment: What Exactly you want, whether to load window other than your MainMenu.xib? If that is the case, in your project u will find a file with your project name ( <project_name -Info.plist>) under Supporting files, open it and you will find "Main nib file base name" there change the value to your new xib name which u want to load. OPTION 2: if u using xcode 4 and above then select your project in the project navigator --> Summary --> there you will find an option "Main Interface" click on the drop down button and select the xib name u want to load first.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically to show frist window you need to set `makeKeyAndOrderFront` in `awakeFromNib` or  in Appdelegate `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`
   It will show your decide window at frist.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

}
```

or

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification`
{

     [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

}
```